# How does one find the relevant universal properties for writing categorical definitions?

Tags: category-theory

For Category Theory purposes, we often rewrite definition from something which involves stuff inside the objects we talk about to some relations between the defined object to other objects in the Category. One easy example I learned is of the set product by considering that given two sets $A,B$, any map factors uniquely through $A \times B$.

But even after seeing this example, I am stuck at one point. How actually does find the Universal property for rewriting a pre-existing definition for category theory purposes?

This has a chance of being pretty board but I feel a bit lost here.

Comment: For starters you can read [this page on universal constructions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+construction) on nLab. In general a universal property of an object $c$ in a category $C$, is characterized by a functor $F : C \rightarrow \text{Set}$ such that there exists an element $x \in Fc$, which induces a natural isomorphism $F \cong \text{Hom(c, -)}$ via the Yoneda Lemma. As such you automatically get a set of morphisms $f : c \rightarrow d$ for any other object $d$ in $C$.

Comment: Your question is rather open. It would be better if you could come up with a specific example that is causing you problems.

Comment: Universal properties are always a description of the morphisms in or out of an object. Turning such a description into a universal property as they are presented usually is a routine application of the Yoneda lemma. The Yoneda lemma is THE lemma of category theory. You do not waste time if you try to understand it. Emily Riehl's book is the best place for that.

Comment: It seems so the other commentar (Nico) is saying that the general set up is to use Yoneda while you are indirectly saying that there is no general pattern...? @RobArthan

Comment: It's open in the sense that you just talk about "some relations", whereas to apply Yoneda, you need to have a definite functor in view. That's why I am encouraging you to be more specific, so that if it's appropriate, we can explain how to apply Yoneda to an example of interest to you.